# Tornado turning off include_version for static_url()

Tags: tornado

I want to turn off the ?v= version information when static_url() is called.

I have the following staticFileHandler class where I try and override the make_static_url() classmethod:

```
class BaseHandlerStatic(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
   @classmethod
   def make_static_url(cls, settings, path, include_version=False):
      super().make_static_url(settings, path, include_version)
```

unfortunately doing this causes my program to crash with at 500 errors:

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado-4.5.dev1-py3.5-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1342, in static_url
        return base + get_url(self.settings, path, **kwargs)
    TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
[E 170213 16:23:32 web:1977] 500 GET / (127.0.0.1) 14.66ms
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong and how I can set include_version to False?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `return` statement:

```
class BaseHandlerStatic(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
   @classmethod
   def make_static_url(cls, settings, path, include_version=False):
      return super().make_static_url(settings, path, include_version)
```

Otherwise your make_static_url returns None implicitly, and the `base + get_url(...)` expression throws an exception trying to catenate `base` with `None`.